# Правильный перевод формата даты

Tags: python, дата

У меня есть строка с датой в таком формате:

```
Thu, 18 Aug 2016 11:38:41 +0300
```

Как перевести ее к такому виду `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` ?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python: parsing date with timezone from an email](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1790795/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790795/parsing-date-with-timezone-from-an-email

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начиная с **python 3.2**:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Переводим строку в объект datetime
d = datetime.strptime('Thu, 18 Aug 2016 11:38:41 +0300', '%a, %d %b %Y %X %z')
# Получаем из объекта строку в нужном формате
print(str(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X')))
```

Для ранних версий можете использовать библиотеку *dateutil*:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Для вывода даты в нужном формате используйте аналогично:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

d = parse('Thu, 18 Aug 2016 11:38:41 +0300')
print(str(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X')))
```

Подробнее о том, какие еще манипуляции с форматом можно делать, читайте внизу [этой документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Comment: У меня Python выдает ошибку `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a, %d %b %Y %X %z'` при запуске скрипта с вашем кодом.

Comment: а какую версию python вы используете?

Comment: 2.7, без `+0300` все отлично

Comment: Да, есть такая [проблема](http://bugs.python.org/issue6641). Но решение тоже есть, я дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Подобный формат даты используется в электронной почте, поэтому можно [`email` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate) из стандартной библиотеки использовать:

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate
>>> tt = parsedate('Thu, 18 Aug 2016 11:38:41 +0300')
>>> tt
(2016, 8, 18, 11, 38, 41, 0, 1, -1)
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tt)
'2016-08-18 11:38:41'
```

Код работает как на Питоне 2 так и 3.

[Принимаемый формат для `strftime()` функции](http://strftime.org/) может зависеть от платформы (от [C `strftime(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)). Если нужна переносимость, то убедитесь, что использованные кода поддерживаются на желаемых платформах.